Attorney conflict of interest
I paid an attorney two years ago to represent me on a case. There's been no recent activity on the case and I asked him if we were beyond the statute of limitations. He cited some incorrect information and I sent him some information showing he was not correct regarding his assumptions. He then got angry that I questioned his guidance and told me he was dropping representation due to a conflict of interest. Does questioning what he is telling me really produce a conflict of interest? Can he just drop my case like that when it's not completed and our contract involves handling the case to completion?

Maybe the reason for his conflict of interest isn't directly related to your action? Maybe he also represents the other party in this (or some other) case?

Not so. The other party is the state. He specifically stated in his text message since I questioned his guidance that there was a conflict of interest.

This is his exact text message.It is not up to you. There is definitely a conflict of interest now because you questioned my legal guidance. I am not texting back and forth. We wish you the best of luck

But the question I asked is whether or not he is justified in dropping my case and saying there's a conflict of interest just for questioning his guidance.

Disagreeing with a lawyer's advice doesn't create a conflict of interest. A conflict only occurs when the lawyer is put in a situation where their loyalties are divided i.e. a hyopthetical scenario might arise where outcome A benefits you, but outcome B benefits either the lawyer or someone who the lawyer has as a client, and the lawyer must choose (or advise you to choose) between A and B.

The other party being the state doesn't mean that the lawyer can't represent them. It would be normal for a lawyer who's hired as a prosecutor or elected as a judge to withdraw from cases where the state was on the other side (but in that case, they should have reached out to you and informed you of your options when they were appointed, not later).

What does your contract say about terminating the representation?

Your lawyer is not there to argue with you. Either you trust your lawyer's advice, or you get another lawyer.

Paul that's not even an answer to my question. No my lawyer is not there to argue with me but when he is clearly 100% wrong and I show him the facts he should just agree with me and go on from there. You're telling me that when you're defending a case that you won't take your clients input. That's assuming you're an attorney but I don't think you are.

Cadence I understand your argument but my lawyer definitely has nothing to do with the state. I gave you the text where he explains the only reason he's terminating representation is because I disagreed with him... period.

united-states
In principle, it is not a conflict of interest to represent a client with whom you don't get along or disagree about legal strategy. However, if there is a truly irreconcilable difference in opinions, the lawyer may be justified in withdrawing from the case. For instance, from the Washington Rules of Professional Conduct:

RPC 1.2 SCOPE OF REPRESENTATION AND ALLOCATION OF AUTHORITY BETWEEN CLIENT
AND LAWYER

(a) Subject to paragraphs (c) and (d), a lawyer shall abide by a client's decisions concerning the objectives of representation and... shall consult with the client as to the means by which they are to be pursued.

Comment
Paragraph (a) confers upon the client the ultimate authority to determine the purposes to be served by legal representation, within the limits imposed by law and the lawyer's professional obligations....
On occasion, however, a lawyer and a client may disagree about the means to be used to accomplish the client's objectives.... The lawyer should consult with the client and seek a mutually acceptable resolution of the disagreement. If such efforts are unavailing and the lawyer has a fundamental disagreement with the client, the lawyer may withdraw from the representation.

RPC 1.16, which covers withdrawal and termination of representation, notes a lawyer may withdraw if:

(4) the client insists upon taking action that the lawyer considers repugnant or with which the lawyer has a fundamental disagreement;
(5) the client fails substantially to fulfill an
obligation to the lawyer regarding the lawyer's
services....
(6) the representation ... has been rendered unreasonably difficult by the client.

If the client's and lawyer's positions cannot be reconciled or their working relationship breaks down, it is the duty of the lawyer to withdraw and allow another counsel to take their place who is more able to zealously advance the client's interests. Whether the parties' conduct in a case rises to the level of requiring the lawyer to withdraw is a specific legal question that Law.SE can't answer.
(Rules of Professional Conduct vary somewhat from state to state. Consult a local lawyer if you're unsure.)

Cadence I can understand that an irreconcilable difference could cause this but this was just one instance where I disagreed with his interpretation of the law. It was clearly 100% incorrect. I showed him the exact law that he was stating incorrectly and he was embarrassed or offended so he decided to claim conflict of interest.

Rule of Professional Conduct 1.8 bars lawyers from seeking prospective malpractice waivers from clients and a threat of a malpractice suit by a client against a lawyer is sometimes described as a concurrent conflict of interest between the lawyer personally and the client since they are potentially adverse to each other (not technically within Rule of Professional Conduct 1.7 but in the same vein).

@KennethBruce We don't analyze the facts of individual cases here. If you hire another lawyer or write to the state bar's disciplinary committee, I'm sure they would be interested in hearing your side of the story.
